# mutex cond wait class error or bug

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have problem with this simple wrapper of mutex / cond wait class. 
I use it to protect queue of connected clients and to notify threads in the wait state that there are new clients connected, but application crashed with Segmentation Failed at

```
client_socket_fd = clients_for_threads_q.front();
```

when its is under stress test only (many clients connected )

Wait at the thread:

```
    MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.lock();
    if ( clients_for_threads_q.empty() )
    {
        MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.wait_signal();
    }

    client_socket_fd = clients_for_threads_q.front(); // CRASHED !!!!
    clients_for_threads_q.pop();
    MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.unlock();
```

of course clients_for_threads_q ptotected on writing

```
    MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.lock();
    clients_for_threads_q.push (client_socket_fd);
    MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.send_signal();
    MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.unlock();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) can have spurious wake ups.

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. **Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() functions may occur**. Since the return from pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

You need to change your waiter `if` condition to a loop:

```
while ( clients_for_threads_q.empty() )
{
    MUTEXCONDSIGNAL_for_workers.wait_signal();
}
```